# What is the trickiest way you have used Android Color State List?

Tags: android, colors

I have used the android color state lists a lot for various things and they seem to not be well known in Android development even though they are really useful. So I want to know what it the trickiest or coolest thing you have down with them?

- Background behind transparent PNGs?
- Changing text colors on Custom Tabs?
- Changing complete layouts?

Let me and others know the potential of this great tool.

[Android ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html)

Comment: How about you give us some examples of what you did. ;) Not sure this really fits in StackOverflow, but I think it could be a fun subject nonetheless.

Comment: @Klaus, sounds good. I will post code tonight after I get back to my pc. I have mainly used it to create custom tabs like the tabs in the recent release of the twitter app.

Comment: Im not looking for code but this resource is really under-used and well known about and I think it would be great for people searching for hints on it to be able to get a feel for its power.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean - I would like to be inspired too. I am working on an application that might take advantage of it, but I have not utilized it yet.

Comment: @Klaus, I added a quick example below. Hopefully more people will post. I havent tried using it for background colors with transparent PNGs in the foreground but I think I will try to think of something where I can use it in order to try in out.

Comment: I thought there would be more input here. Guess people really do not know about this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ColorStateList for tabs:

```
ColorStateList tabCSL = ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(),
  resources.getXml(R.color.tab_text_csl));

TabHost host = getTabHost();
TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("tab1");

TextView txtTab = new TextView(this);
txtTab.setText(R.string.tab_string);
txtTab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
txtTab.setTextColor(tabCSL);
spec.setIndicator(txtTab);
spec.setContent(someIntentYouMadeEarlier);
host.addTab(spec);
```

XML of `/res/color/tab_text_csl.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/white" />
   <item android:color="@color/dark_grey"/>
</selector>
```